# Different results each time model is trained

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have created a simple Keras model which fits to the points I've created as shown in below image. My problem is that when I run the code, I can't always get this red line (maybe in 1 run of 5 runs I get the desired result. In other 4 runs I get a straight line). What should I do to make my model fit always?
Is this related to [randomness](https://machinelearningmastery.com/randomness-in-machine-learning/)

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(2,activation = 'linear'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation = 'linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001))

history = model.fit(X,y, epochs=1500, verbose=False)
y_hat = model.predict(X)**strong text**
```

[pyplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYkVe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the initial weights of your network get randomly initialized. To get reproducable results, you must set a seed for the random numbers. The random initialization of the weights is based on this seed. Having the same seed will therefore always result in the same initialization.

Taken from https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/
that is:

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
```

The seed values can have any number of course, but must be fixed.